# Tools to inspect local network, and find local IP address of device?

Tags: networking, utilities

This is my specific context (Latex/TikZ code for the diagram below):

[image: netlan.png]

Now this local "Router", has broke down several times, and several different devices have had its role (sometimes they have a wireless interface too, sometimes not; currently, as on the image, they don't). The same goes for the "Cable modem". However, regardless of such differences, I typically experience that:

- I can just wire this setup, and I get internet on the (Ubuntu GNU/Linux) PCs without any further tinkering with setups
- The local addresses of the PCs and the Router are always known (e.g. I can use tools like `nmap` to list the addresses of the local PCs and the local router).
- The "global"/Public IP is always known on the local PCs (through the use of [whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com/) and such)

The problem is the cable modem. I know it serves an administration page on port 80, because I've seen it before, when I had a different router. But, the thing is, I had forgotten what local IP is this cablemodem webpage supposed to be served on - I think with my previous local router, there was a page on its web interface which listed the cable modem local IP; I cannot find the same in the current router.

So, the thing is - I want to access the administration page of the cable modem from PC1-3, but don't know what its local address should be; the other addresses are known as on the image. What tools (command-line or GUI) and approaches could I use, to find the cable modem's web server local IP address?

Code for diagram:

```tex
% drawn with tikzedt; to compile,
% save as test.tex, and call: `pdflatex test.tex`
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\pagecolor{yellow!15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{rcn} = [draw,rectangle,inner sep=10pt,line width=1pt,align=center];
\tikzstyle{ln} = [line width=1pt]
\tikzstyle{cln} = [shape=cloud,draw,line width=1pt,fill=black!10,minimum width=10em,aspect=1.2]
\tikzstyle{cln2} = [shape=cloud,cloud puffs=20,draw,line width=0.5pt,inner sep=0pt,align=center,aspect=3]

\node[rcn] (PC1) at (1,4) {PC1\\Local IP: 10.0.0.2};
\node[rcn] (PC2) at (1,2.5) {PC2\\Local IP: 10.0.0.3};
\node[rcn] (PC3) at (1,1) {PC3\\Local IP :10.0.0.4};

\node[rcn] (Router) at (6,2.5) {Router\\Local IP: 10.0.0.1\\\small(wired,LAN)};
\node[rcn] (Modem) at (10.5,2.5) {Cable modem\\Local IP: ??.??.??.??\\\small(wired,wireless,router)};
\node[cln] (Internet) at (15,2.5) {\Large Internet};


\draw[ln] (PC1) -| (3.5,3) -| (Router.west);
\draw[ln] (PC2) -| (Router.west);
\draw[ln] (PC3) -| (3.5,2) -| (Router.west);

\draw [ln](Router) -- (Modem) -- (Internet);
\node [cln2] at (10.5121,4.7455) {Public IP (known):\\AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If networking as such still works - what does a **traceroute www.google.com** tell you? :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @tink - I forgot to mention, that while local networking is in order, usually I mostly want to look at the cable modem page when I lose the Internet `:)` So it would be nice with a LAN-based only solution. Internet is back for me now, so I tried your command; but for some reason, the `traceroute` command gives me "all stars": ` 1  * * *`, ` 2  * * *` up to `30  * * *`. Cheers!

Comment: Google the modem's model and find the default IP for the web admin interface

Comment: @sdaau: is your workstation blocking all ICMP packets? :)

Comment: I have a similar setup behind a DSL modem. You should be able to go to the admin page of "Router" and extract the information from there. It is often called the default gateway on the **WAN**